# RandomStr Missing Operator or Semicolon error

Tags: delphi-10-seattle, delphi-10.3-rio

```
function Randomstring(strLen: Integer): string;
var
  ID: string;
begin
  ID := 'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890';  
  Result := '';
  Repeat
    Result := Result + ID[Random(Length(ID)) + 1];
  until (Length(Result) = strLen)
end;
```

*All the semicolons seem just fine to me. What am I missing?*

Comment: This code compiles fine, isn't it? *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the `until` statement:

```
until (Length(Result) = strLen); // <-- here
```

Comment: Thanks and yes that may have been an issue but also a component i had was messing with the function, so i used math to generate randomrange integer which did the trick for me.